# Change background for all artboards in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I have Sketch file with 30 pages and 10 artboards on every page (App Store screenshots for 30 languages)
Is there any way to select all 30*10 = 300 artboards and change background color? I'm tired of clicking and doing this for every page.
Found only "Replace Colour" script to replace text color, not artboard background.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three ways of going about this:

1. Changing all the artboard background colors (*Easy*)
2. Creating a `Symbol` and making that the backlist layer (*Hard, but extremely flexible*)
3. Creating a `Shared Style` for the background (*Hard, and not as flexible*)

It might be more work to do the second and third way, but if you change your mind later, it'll take 5 seconds.

For flexibility, I'd opt for the `Symbol` approach, just in case you want the background to be something other than a solid color.

---

That said, if you wanted to head down the first path, here's a 10x easier way than clicking 300+ times.

[image: Collapse layer list in Sketch]

By using the `View > Layer List > Collapse All Groups` menu option, you're fingers will thank you.